# Moderator said I can vote to close, but I cannot due to bounty

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flagging, bounty

[How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

The meta discussion says that to close a question with a bounty, you should raise a flag.  I did that.  The flag was declined.  This question is not about why it was declined, but rather about the moderator's statement that "You can vote to close if you like."  How?

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can *unilaterally* close bountied questions, and refund the bounty, as explained in the linked meta question. However, I would use such a heavy intervention only for blatantly off-topic questions or egregiously problematic ones. I don't see, at the moment, any such case.

For all other questions, I suggest to let the bounty follow its cycle and then vote to close, so that other regular users can vote on it.

Comment: Am I supposed to see recently completed bounties somewhere?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist No, there isn't any direct way to search for questions that had bounties (there is just a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/query/648267/list-bounties)). If you just want to retrieve the one you flagged, you can look at the flags' page on your profile.